# How to send an audio file in Cordova using ajax?

Tags: ajax, cordova, audio, mp3

Is there any way to send a mp3 file to server in Cordova using ajax?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have use `cordova-file-transfer` plugin

Example:

```
var transfer = new FileTransfer();
transfer.upload(FILE_ABSOLUTE_PATH, "http://example.com/upload", function(sucess){
  // success callback
  console.log(success);
 }, function(fail){
  // failure callback
  console.error(fail);
 });
```

example on absolute path in Android : `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/.....`

Comment: Thanks. I had seen that. But i had a problem when i tried to save the mp3 file on backend.

I'm using this java rest (using MultipartHttpServletRequest):

@RequestMapping(value="/{clientId}/conversation/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 @ResponseBody String chat(@PathVariable("clientId") String clientId, HttpSession session, MultipartHttpServletRequest request){}

But i don't know how to save this mp3 file on disk? Do i need to apply some Encoder?

Note: In Cordova i used options.mimeType="audio/mpeg";

Answer (score 0):

use [cordova-file-transfer](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/) plugin

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I had seen that. But i had a problem when i tried to save the mp3 file on back-end.

I'm using this java rest (using MultipartHttpServletRequest):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{clientId}/conversation/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        @ResponseBody String chat(@PathVariable("clientId") String clientId, HttpSession session, MultipartHttpServletRequest request){}
```

But i don't know how to save this mp3 file on disk? Do i need to apply some Encoder?

Note: In Cordova i used options.mimeType="audio/mpeg";